# Updating bound Progressbar

Tags: c#, wpf

Hej im trying to fix this problem for **days** now.

I've got a `ListBox` with a `ProgressBar` , binded to a `ObservableCollection`. Now im downloading stuff and trying to update the `ProgressBar` with:

```
public delegate void BytesDownloadedEventHandler(ByteArgs e, Item Obj);
public static event BytesDownloadedEventHandler bytesDownloaded;
```

Heres the `Event` where im getting the right `Obj` from the `ObservableCollection`

```
private void MainWindow_bytesDownloaded(ByteArgs e,  Item Obj) {
    if (Obj != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < _downloadList.Count; i++) {
            if (_downloadList[i].Name == Obj.Name) {
                if (_downloadList[i].Value + e.downloaded <= _downloadList[i].Maximum) {
                    App.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(delegate {
                        _downloadList[i].Minimum = 0;
                        _downloadList[i].Maximum = e.total;
                        _downloadList[i].Value += e.downloaded;

                        lstDowload.ItemsSource = _downloadList;
                    });
                }

                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and heres the `ListBox` code with the `ProgressBar`

```
<ListBox Name="lstDowload" Height="350" Width="707" Visibility="Collapsed" Canvas.Left="-9">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Canvas Height="67" Width="682">
                <Canvas.ToolTip>
                    <ToolTip Name="albumToolTip" Width="Auto" Height="Auto">
                        <Canvas Width="120" Height="150">
                            <Image Source="{Binding ToolTipImage}" Height="152" Width="125" Stretch="Fill"/>
                        </Canvas>
                    </ToolTip>
                </Canvas.ToolTip>
                <ProgressBar Width="288" Canvas.Left="53" Canvas.Top="53" Height="10" Value="{Binding Value}" Maximum="{Binding Maximum}" Minimum="{Binding Minimum}"/>
                <Label Foreground="#FFC3BDBD" FontFamily="{DynamicResource HeaderFontFamily}" FontSize="11" Content="{Binding Name}" Canvas.Left="48" Canvas.Top="15"/>
                <Label Foreground="#FF8D8D8D" FontFamily="{DynamicResource HeaderFontFamily}" FontSize="12" Content="{Binding Status}" Canvas.Left="48" Canvas.Top="30"/>
                <Image Source="{Binding DownloadIcon}" Height="39" Width="49" Canvas.Left="-1" Canvas.Top="6"/>
            </Canvas>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

My Item Properties

```
public string Name { get; set; }

public Uri DownloadIcon { get; set; }

public int Value {get; set;}

public double Maximum { get; set; }
    public int Minimum { get; set; }
```

Now my problem is that the `ProgressBar` just stays at 100% and nothing happens.
Maybe somebody could give me a hint or something. This is to complicated for me :) im trying everything but still the same :(

Comment: Yeah that happens while Copying my code here ... Thanks

Comment: What is the type of `_downloadList[i]`? Does it implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`?

Comment: _downloadList[i] is the ObservableCollection i think it does but i never worked with INotifyPropertyChanged thats why im avoiding it .

Comment: No, I'm assuming `_downloadList` is the ObservableCollection. What type is *each item*? Each item must implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Comment: See my Answer ive added the Item Properties

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The item type used in the ObservableCollection must implement INotifyPropertyChanged for the UI to take note of the changes.

Also since you're using an observable collection you only need to assign the ItemsSource once, actually you can bind it to a property on whatever object you assign to be your windows Datacontext

Something like:

```
public class Item : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Double value;

    public Double Value
    {
        get { return this.value; }
        set { this.value = value; Changed("Value"); }
    }
    private Double minimum;

    public Double Minimum
    {
        get { return minimum; }
        set { minimum = value; Changed("Minimum"); }
    }
    private Double maximum;

    public Double Maximum
    {
        get { return maximum; }
        set { maximum = value; Changed("Maximum"); }
    }

    private string name;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; Changed("Name"); }
    }

    private string status;

    public string Status
    {
        get { return status; }
        set { status = value; Changed("Status"); }
    }

    private void Changed(string propertyName)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

Here's the xaml used for testing:

```
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                <ProgressBar Width="288" Height="10" Value="{Binding Value}" Maximum="{Binding Maximum}" Minimum="{Binding Minimum}"/>
                    <Label Foreground="#FFC3BDBD" FontSize="11" Content="{Binding Name}"/>
                    <Label Foreground="#FF8D8D8D" FontSize="12" Content="{Binding Status}" />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

And the code behind...

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    Timer timer2 = new Timer(3000);
    Timer timer = new Timer(100);
    Dispatcher gui = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Items = new ObservableCollection<Item>();
        this.DataContext = this;

        timer.Elapsed += (s, e) =>
        {
            gui.Invoke(() => new Action(() =>
                {
                    foreach (Item item in Items)
                    {
                        if (item.Value < item.Maximum)
                        {
                            item.Value++;
                        }
                    }
                }).Invoke());
        };
        timer.Enabled = true;

        Random rand = new Random();

        timer2.Elapsed += (s, e) =>
            {
                gui.Invoke(() =>                         
                Items.Add(new Item()
                {
                    Minimum = rand.Next(1, 30),
                    Maximum = rand.Next(35, 100),
                }));
            };
        timer2.Enabled = true;
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Item> Items
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do i need to take car of something in my Xaml code?  And am i updating the progressbar right in private void MainWindow_bytesDownloaded(ByteArgs e,  Item Obj) ?

Comment: I'd stop reassigning the list on every byte downloaded but apart from that you should be ok, normally I'd use a separate object as a ViewModel that is assigned to the DataContext of the form but it's not a requirement.

Comment: Thanks for your awesome Answer James !! I will try this when im Home . Thank you

Comment: But how could i Update the Progressbar with the actual bytes ive Downloaded ?

Comment: You update the `Value` property of the item. It notifies anything listening that it's changed. The Data Template of the Listbox is listening to the Items for change events and updates the UI. The list itself hasn't changed only it's items properties. Same thing when you add a new item; the list notifies anything that's listening that it's items have changed. The Listbox reloads its *contents*, the list itself hasn't changed

Comment: Ive done it exactly as you told me but its still staying at 100% and not updating...am i missing something

Comment: @iNCEPTiON_Must be! The code I posted compiles and produces filling progress bars in a list box (After resolving some usings)

Comment: Im sorry had a little xaml syntax error now it work great . Thanks for your help